# Returning to a specific tab opened in previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

In my app there's an activity (Activity 1) with some tabs. From this activity it is possible to start another activity (Activity 2), from which, after completing a task, the app returns back to Activity 1. 
This return shows always the first tab in Activity1, while I'd like to see the tab that was selected before starting Activity 2. This, in fact, happens successfully when I press the back button and I want to replicate it in the Activity2->Activity1 intent. How can I accomplish it, possibly without passing the number of the selected tab from an activity to another? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: MrCurious is on the right track but may have went a bit too far.  Just calling `finish()` when you're ready to go back to Activity 1 will probably get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity 2, which is not your main activity(i guess)
you can make a back button as a navigation icon and inside the navigation icon click you can write `onBackPressed()` and `this.finish()` methods.
as you go to next activity your current Activity1 will go to stack and again after Activity2 finishes it comes to top with the state it was left. 
See Like this

```
your Activity1{
 ..
 //startActivity(Activity2)
 //some code to launch Activity2
 ..
}
```

here your Activity1 will start activity2 and go back on stack with the same state which is currently displaying !

Now In your Activity2

```
Your Activity2{
     //any button which will trigger the Activity1
     //inside it's onCLick(), add this
     ...
     onClick(View v){
        onBackPressed();
        finish();
      }
     //so that your current Activity2 will get finished and lead you
     //to the mainActivity i.e Activity1

   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you suggested. In the onClick method of the button which leads from Activity2 to Activity1 (it's in a fragment) I've written after the intent `getActivity().finish()` but it didn't help. Should I replace the intent lines with the call to finish() method?

Comment: The solution itself works, but I need to pass some data from Activity2 to Activity1. I've tried to realize this through the bundle instead of the intent, but it doesn't seem to work (I mean, the tab selection is kept, but the data don't pass from Activity2 to Activity1). Any suggestions?

Comment: Then you need to use Intent putExtras() method or Bundle Reference which  allows you to send data/intents to previous activity but again it'll be starting a new Activity which will lose your previous state of activity. Instead of this try to search for savedInstanceState()

Comment: if your Activity2 should return some value to Activity1, then you should probably start Activity2 with startActivityForResult method and override onActivityResult method in Activity1.